# OpenERP 7 synchronization with play application

Tags: security, playframework, oauth-2.0, odoo, openerp-7

I'm trying to make http requests between a play application and OpenERP 7.  Both apps are located on separated Ubuntu VM,  using login-encrypted password authentication. I need to know if is possible to use oauth to control the access between apps without OpenERP db-filter (i.e multidb), or is another solution for secure communications with this environment